# Will a tree always be obtained as a result of vertices contraction algorithm?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

I am working on the algorithm for vertex contraction of a weighted undirected graph. The graph is spatial and its vertices have (x, y) coordinates. The edge weighs are the Euclidian distance between two vertices. As my graph is undirected I don't have head and tail of an edge, and I will use "left" and "right" to distingush the endpoints.

Currently, the algorithm includes these steps.

1. Find all bridges of a graph.
2. Take the longest bridge.
3. If there are more vertices on the "left" side, then contraction to the "left" vertex of the bridge; otherwise, contraction to the "right" vertex.
4. Mark the bridge as passed.
5. If there are bridges not passed, then go to step 2, otherwise go to step 6.
6. End.

For the illustration I have prepared a toy graph where bridges are denoted by red colors. The red vertex is the cut-node in the chain (two bridge on both sides) and green vertices are cut-nodes.

[image]

**Question.** I am looking for the limit case. Is it possible to obtain a tree after of running the proposed vertex contraction algorithm for all cases?